# Random lags and crashes on Android 5 with LibGDX

Tags: android, crash, garbage-collection, libgdx, android-5.0-lollipop

I am developing a mobile game - [Spatium](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.basicks.spatium.android) - it is already on the Play Store.
The game is made via LibGDX. I have porblems on Android 5 (Lollipop): The game randomly stops drawing for 2-3 seconds. The biggest problem is the "Native crash at /system/lib/libc.so" - the app just gets killed in time - sometimes I can play for minutes, other times - it just crashes after seconds.

I am testing on Samsung Galaxy S2 (cyanogenmod 12 - AOSP 5.0.2). I thought that the problem is that I am not using the licensed firmware but no - the problem is the same on Nexus 5 and HTC (both with Android 5.0.1 and 5.0.2).

Here is the full crash from LogCat in debug mode: http://jpst.it/xLgY

I have 2 crash reports on my Developer Console: http://jpst.it/xLhV

I saw that the new GC is called all the time on my S2 and then I put largeHeap="true" in the manifest but nothing changed.
Here is small log from the GC - http://jpst.it/xLi2

I thought that I have to compile it with the new SDK and the latest version of LibGDX - last night i updated my SDK (via SDK manager) and updated the LibGDX project version but nothing changed...

I am browsing the internet for fix since 5 days and I didn't found anything, so I hope that someone will help me here.

Thank you!

Comment: btw, I am using [AssetManager](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets) for loading my assets in all of my games and it works fine

Comment: My guess is that the GC is tripping over a corrupted object.  Its not really a GC issue.  The OpenGL and sound APIs use native buffers, and you can pass bad parameters/data into them through Libgdx.  (It generally protects against such things but cannot always.)  Are you perhaps disposing of things too early?